# Загрузка изображения в Dialog с помощью Glide

Tags: java, android

Как вставить изображение в Dialog с помощью библиотеки Glide?

Пытаюсь загрузить так, но не получается.

```
 button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SkullActivity.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            image.setImageResource(Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.history_button).asBitmap().format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888).into(image));

            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Ошибка в `Glide.with(this)` cannot resolve method.

Comment: что именнозначит "не получается"? в чем проблема?

Comment: Вы уверены, что ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView3); не получается null?

Comment: Я на самом деле уже успел найти исходники библиотеки, и определить, в чем у вас проблема, и даже знаю решение. Но напишу ответ, как только вы оформите вопрос, как полагается - указав хотя бы конкретную проблему. Не просто  "не получается".

Comment: И какой же тип у параметра, который надо передать в этот метод? Вы уверены, что вы передаете тот параметр?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема, что вы вызывая `Glide.with(this)` вместо `Context` отправляете `OnClickListener`

Comment: жаль, а я хотел, чтобы автор сам чему-то научился... А вы ему "на тарелочке"...

Comment: Сорри, я уже после увидел твой коммент. Думаю, ваш коммент в любом случае полвиял на автора

Comment: Та ничего страшного, просто хотел ,как в той пословице про "дашь человеку рыбу, и он будет сыт 1 день..."